# racket -e with quotes

Tags: command-line, racket

On a Windows 10 machine, the following command to evaluate an expression and enter the REPL:

```
racket -e '(display "hi\n")' -i
```

produces the following error (likely because the first `"` cuts short the expression):

```
#f::2: read: expected a `)' to close `('
```

Is there a workaround? I need the inner quotation marks to [execute a file in the REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875182/racket-execute-file-and-stay-in-interactive-mode): `'(enter! "foo.rkt")'`.

**Update.** No matter how I try to escape the `"`, it seems that Windows strips all the quotes (and even the backslash) before sending the argument to Rackets. To wit:

```
C:\pf\Racket>racket -e "(display ""hi\n"")" -i
Welcome to Racket v6.5.
hin: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

C:\pf\Racket>racket -i -e "(enter! """"""""hello_world.rkt"""""")"
Welcome to Racket v6.5.
#f::1: enter!: not a module path or #f
  at: hello_world.rkt
  in: (enter! hello_world.rkt)
```

Comment: That works totally fine for me running Racket 6.5 on OS X. Is it possible that this has something to do with Windows command-line parsing? I unfortunately don’t have a Windows machine on hand to try it out on.

Comment: did you try reversing the order of quotes, i.e. `racket -i "(display 'hi\n')" -i` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Unfortunately, I did.

Comment: @shellter that won't work as single quotes have different meanings to racket. Perhaps using double quotes on both but with escaping will work?

Comment: @Sylwester I was thinking the same thing, but it didn't work (see update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
racket -e "(display \"hi\n\")" -i
```