# Command-line Racket: Run xrepl commands using -e flag in interactive terminal

Tags: racket

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876947) that mentions entering a racket file using XREPL as shown below:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket vX.X.X.
-> ,en foo.rkt
42
"foo.rkt">
```

What would be the way to type in the first line while calling racket from the command-line itself?
Something like:

`$ racket -ie ',en foo.rkt'`

however, the above line outputs the following error:

```
Welcome to Racket v7.2.
string::1: unquote: not in quasiquote
  in: (unquote en)
  location...:
   string::1
  context...:
   do-raise-syntax-error
   expand-capturing-lifts
   temp118_0
   temp91_0
   compile15
   temp85_0
>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Racket 8.5.

```
racket -i -e '(enter! "foo.rkt")'
```