# SICP: Evaluate Racket into REPL with Emacs and Geiser

Tags: emacs, racket, sicp, mit-scheme, geiser

Working through SICP using Emacs, Geiser, and MIT Scheme, I decided to switch over to Racket in order to properly do the exercises in section 2.2.4 involving the Picture Language.

## Configuration

I got a setup together that works for MIT Scheme and Racket using the following `~/.emacs` configuration:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(setq geiser-mit-binary "/usr/bin/scheme")
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/usr/bin/racket")
(setq geiser-active-implementations '(mit racket))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rkt\\'" . geiser-mode))
```

## Workflow with MIT Scheme

Here's my workflow for working with MIT Scheme:

First, I open a file (`fib.scm`) using `emacs fib.scm`. I'm asked to pick the Scheme implementation, which I answer with `mit`.

Second, I write my `fib` function, press `C-c C-z` to open a REPL.

Third, I switch back to the code buffer with `C-x o` and evaluate it using `C-c C-b`.

Fourth, I switch to the REPL buffer with `C-x o` and evaluate some expressions.

This it how it looks like:

[image: MIT Scheme with Geiser in Emacs]

## Workflow with Racket

Here's my (intended) workflow for working with the SICP language of Racket:

First, I open a file (`fib.rkt`) using `emacs fib.rkt`. **Interestingly, I'm not asked to pick a Scheme implementation.**

Second, I write my `fib` function, but use `#lang sicp` in the first line. Then I open the REPL using `C-c C-z`.

Third, I switch back to the code buffer with `C-x o` and evaluate it using `C-c C-b`, which gives no error message, but prints `=> #<void>` at the very bottom.

Fourth, I switch back to the REPL buffer with `C-x o`, **where I fail to evaluate an expression like `(fib 3)`**:

```
  2 racket@> (fib 3)                                                                       
  3 fib: undefined;                                                                        
  4  cannot reference an identifier before its definition                                  
  5   in module: top-level                                                                 
  6   context...:                                                                          
  7    body of top-level                                                                   
  8    /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

This it how it looks like:

[image: Racket with Geiser in Emacs]

**What am I doing wrong?** Is it the configuration, is it the way I use it?

### Example with `sicp-pict`

When I run the following code using the Racket workflow from above, the picture of Einstein is properly displayed:

```lisp
#lang sicp
(#%require sicp-pict)
(paint einstein)
```

So my setup is not entirely broken…

## Addendum

Having re-installed the `geiser-racket` package, I'm now able to start a REPL. I'm also able to evaluate the entire buffer using `C-c C-b`, which prints `=> #<void>` to the bottom of the screen.

However, when I try to actually invoke a function, I get this error:

```
  1 Welcome to Racket v8.6 [cs].                                                                          
  2 racket@> (fib 3)                                                                                      
  3 +: contract violation                                                                                 
  4   expected: number?                                                                                   
  5   given: #<procedure:fib>                                                                             
  6   context...:                                                                                         
  7    /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/norm-define.rkt:52:83: body of top-level                 
  8    /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

[image: The error in the Racket REPL]

**Edit**: Oh dear, it was a simple syntax error... my bad! Everything is fine now!

[image: working fib implementation]

Comment: You need one of the options. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875182/racket-execute-file-and-stay-in-interactive-mode

Comment: @soegaard I created a file `~/.local/bin/racket-interactive`, which calls `racket -i`, and use this `racket-interactive` as the `geiser-racket-binary`. Now I can't even switch between the (slowly starting) REPL and the editor buffer.

Comment: Time to look at racket-mode.com instead.

Comment: It seems there is a geiser-racket package.
But I recommend racket-mode. It is the most used Emacs mode for Racket.
https://github.com/emacsmirror/geiser-racket/

Comment: @soegaard Interesting; I thought that I already had installed `geiser-racket`, but it wasn't listed as installed. So I re-installed it and also removed the line `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rkt\\'" . geiser-mode))` from my `~/.emacs`. How the REPL works!

Comment: I mean: "_Now_ the REPL works!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finish things up, I just post the steps I have taken to get everything to run:

Use `melpa` instaed of `melpa-stable` (`~/emacs`):

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Refresh the packages after re-opening Emacs:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
```

Install `racket-mode`:

```
M-x package-install RET racket-mode
```

Install the package `geiser-racket`:

```
M-x package-install RET geiser-racket
```

Extend your Geiser config (`~/emacs`):

```
(setq geiser-mit-binary "/usr/bin/scheme")
(setq geiser-racket-binary "/usr/bin/racket")
(setq geiser-active-implementations '(mit racket))
```

Start using the picture language:

```
#lang sicp
(#%require sicp-pict)
(paint einstein)
```

Open it in Emacs:

```
emacs ../examples/einstein.rkt
```

Start a Racket REPL and evaluate the whole buffer:

```
C-c C-z
C-x o
C-c C-b
```

An image of Einstein should appear.